# android: memory usage is increasing each time on tab click (when using activitygroup)

Tags: android, tabs, memory-management, activitygroup

I am using an activity group in my application to show the tabs.

Each time when I click on any tab, its total memory usage increases by 1 MB. And also if I again go to any inner activity within that tab, its memory usage increases again.

I am using `getLocalActivityManager()` to start activities.

```
    //argIntent this is my intent
    //argActivityId is the id ot activity

     argIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // the id is stored in an arraylist
     int intListSize = arlstGroup.size();

     arlstGroup.add(intListSize, argActivityId);
     Window objWindow = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(argActivityId, argIntent);
     View objView = objWindow.getDecorView();
     setContentView(objView);
```

and also i am using destroyActivity() for destroying each activity but the memory-usage is still increaing.

Then I tried with destroying all activities from localActivityManger when each sub activity  starts. The problem still remains though.

How can I solve this problem?

Please help me...

Comment: I am also phase the same Problem. Jomia if you get the Solution please share it..

Answer (score 0):

Do you use large objects (Drawables, Bitmaps etc.) in your activities? Check this article for details about avoiding memory leaks:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html